# Usage des prépositions « à » et « en » avec les noms de saison

Tags: usage, prépositions

Pour spécifier la saison au cours de laquelle prend place un évènement ou au cours de laquelle se passe quelque chose on utilise presque toujours « en » lorsque la saison est l'hiver ou l'été ; si on y pense bien on s'aperçoit que l'on dit plutôt peu « en automne » et  que l'on ne dit pas « en printemps » ; cela est confirmé par les [fréquences pour « **en** »](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=en+%C3%A9t%C3%A9%2Cen+hiver%2Cen+automne%2Cen+printemps&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cen%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cen%20hiver%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cen%20automne%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cen%20printemps%3B%2Cc0) : on ne dit pratiquement pas « en printemps ». Si on s'intéresse aux [fréquences pour « **à le** »](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A0+l%27automne%2C%C3%A0+l%27hiver%2Cau+printemps%2C%C3%A0+l%27%C3%A9t%C3%A9&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20l%27%20automne%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20l%27%20hiver%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cau%20printemps%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20l%27%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0) on s'aperçoit que l'expression pour le printemps est la plus fréquente. Il est donc évident que à la place de « en printemps » on dit « au printemps ».

Comment ce phénomène s'expliquerait-il?

Comment: Une très rapide recherche GG fournissant en première page au moins 3 sites donnant les 3 explications (qui n'en font qu'une d'ailleurs) dites-nous plutôt ce qui, relativement à cette explication très rationnelle, vous laisse encore perplexe.

Comment: Ha! Pardon! Si effectivement c'est le niveau étude savante que vous attendez, je ne connais alors pas. Et je doute même que cela existe sur ce sujet tant je connais peu de chercheurs s'engager sur un problème dont la solution tient en 3 lignes de simples évidences.

Comment: Si j'ai bien compris votre question voici un site (1er lien sur google) qui explique pourquoi on utilise en/au https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/quelle-pr%C3%A9position-porter-cette-saison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le phénomène est similaire à celui observé pour les noms de pays (les masculins commençants avec une consonne apparaissent avec la contraction *au(x)* tandis que ceux commençant par une voyelle apparaissent avec *en*) et a les mêmes causes.

En ancien français, les saisons s'utilisaient généralement sans article, et avec la préposition *en*. Quand *en* était suivie d'un article défini, elle formait des contractions similairement à *à* et à *de*. La contraction de *en* et de *le* était au début *el* jusqu'à la vocalisation du /l/ final, à quel point elle a commencé à être épelée *eu* puis *ou*.

Par example, ce bout de texte issus des *Coutumes du Beauvaisis* (fin du XIIIe siècle):

> Es blés somés el printans, poent les gens aler, por querre les erbes et les porées

Traduction libre: "Dans les (champs de) grains semés au printemps, peuvent aller les gens, pour chercher les herbes et les légumes"

Certaines copies plus tardives de ce texte ont "ou printans" à la place de "el printans".

En moyen français, les prononciations des contractions *au* et *ou* ont fini par converger en /o/ fermé. *As* et *es* suivent par analogie le mouvement, devenant toutes deux *aux* (/o:s/ initialement). Cela créant un problème potentiel de compréhension, les locuteurs commencent à replacer de plus en plus les combinaisons de *en* et article défini avec la préposition *dans*, qui jusque là avait une signification plus proche de l'actuel *à l'intérieur*. Ce remplacement mène à la situation moderne, où *en* et *dans* sont presque en distribution complémentaire, le premier apparaissant avec des pronoms et des groupes nominaux sans articles et le second avec des GN avec articles (à quelques exceptions près, surtout des locutions fossilisées comme "en l’occurrence").

Deux de ces exceptions sont les noms de pays et les saisons, chez qui les articles définis se sont répandus au même moment où le système prépositionnel du français connaissait les chamboulements décrits ci-dessus.

Avec ces noms s'est développé un système hybride, les anciennes contractions de *en* (maintenant identique à celle de *à*) restant utilisées dans les contextes où elles auraient été possibles dans la langue ancienne, et un *en* sans article s'imposant dans les cas où la contraction ne se faisait pas, c'est à dire les noms masculins singuliers commençant par une voyelle et les féminins singuliers, sauf si la syntaxe impose l'utilisation d'un article (en hiver -> l'hiver dernier; en Belgique -> dans la Belgique de papa).

En résumé (ancien français -> moyen français -> français moderne):

> (m. sg.) "El printans" ou "en printans" -> "ou printens" ou "en printens" -> "au printemps"
>
> (m. sg. avec entame vocalique) "En l'yvern" ou "en yvern" -> "en l'hiver" ou "en hiver" -> "l'hiver" ou "en hiver"
>
> (f. sg) "En la France" ou "en France" -> "En la France" ou "en France" -> "dans la France" ou "en France"
>
> (pl.) "Es Pays de par deça"(*) -> "Aux Pays-bas"

(*) La première attestation de ce terme date de 1409, donc du moyen français.